# Training Tesseract OCR for a specific document

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have recently started learning and experimenting with Tesseract OCR. I have done a training for a new font using the `tesstrain`.

Now my use case is that I want to train Tesseract 5 for a specific document attached below.
[image]

I have found some articles and tutorials about training for new font or new language but I couldn't find something about training for a custom document.

Is it possible to train Tesseract 5 for my document? If yes, please give me some guidelines on how to proceed with this and if I need any other tools other than Tesseract itself.

I have Tesseract 5 installed on Ubuntu 22.04.